# Pandas Row mean with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a sample pandas DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size =(6,2)),columns=["A","B"])
df.loc[2,"B"]=np.NaN
df
```

Sample DF:

```
    A    B
0   5   0.0
1   4   8.0
2   6   NaN
3   8   9.0
4   4   7.0
5   5   4.0
```

I am trying to get the `mean` of the entire DF, in `DataFrame` format:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.mean(axis=0)).transpose()
```

OP:

```
      A          B
0   5.333333    5.6
```

The `OP` is correct for column `A`, but for column `B` the OP is `5.6` because of `28/5` but it is originally `6` rows and it is neglecting the row with `NaN` value, is there any way to include that row as well?

Expected OP - where for column `A` its `32/6` and for column `B` its `28/6`:

```
      A          B
0   5.333333    4.66666666
```

Comment: `df.sum(0)/len(df)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplier is replace missing values to `0`, then [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for one column `DataFrame` and transpose:

```
df = df.fillna(0).mean().to_frame().T
print (df)
          A         B
0  5.333333  4.666667
```

Or `yatu` solution from comment divide sum of DataFrame by length:

```
df = df.sum().div(len(df)).to_frame().T
print (df)
          A         B
0  5.333333  4.666667
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But one question, though if all the values in a column are ```NaN``` it will be changed to ```0``` which is wrong. Any suggestions to handle this edge case?